# Make every state(area) of the map click able

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Please Help
[image: Map]
I want every part of this map clickable exact with it starting left right top and bottom ending point
I will be very thankful
Regards
Akmal Rasool

Comment: You need to post your problem code.

Comment: Nobody will write code for you. Have a go yourself and if you get stuck then put your code on here for help with specific parts of it.

Comment: What you looking for is html `<map>`

Comment: I would recommend having a look at this to get you started http://jvectormap.com/maps/countries/usa/

Comment: Yes a simple html map @Morpheus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called image mapping. [Here](http://www.image-maps.com/) is a website that will do it for you. Or search google

Alternatively use Dreamweaver(better)